# Java gzip pdf from url to file - result gives minor character mismatch

Tags: java, file, url, pdf, gzip

I'm trying to download a gzip pdf from an url, unpacking it and writing it to a file. It almost works, but currently some characters in the pdf made from my code mismatches the real pdf. I checked this by opening both of the pdf's in notepad.

I provide some short text samples from the two pdfs.

From my code:

> ’8  /qªMiUe°Ä[H`ðKíulýªäqvA®v8;xÒhÖßÚ²ý!Æ¢ØK$áýçpF[¸t1@y$93

From the real pdf:

> ƒ8  /qªMiUe°Ä[H`ðKíulªäqvA®—v8;ŸÒhÖßÚ²!ˆ¢ØK$áçpF[¸t1@y$‘‹3

Here is my code:

```
public void readPDFfromURL(String urlStr) throws IOException {
        URL myURL = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
        urlCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        urlCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlCon.setDoInput(true);
        urlCon.connect();
        Reader reader;
        if ("gzip".equals(urlCon.getContentEncoding())) {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream()));
        }
        else {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream());
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("document.pdf");
        int data = reader.read();
        while(data != -1) {
            char c = (char) data;
            fos.write(c);
            data = reader.read();
        }
        fos.close();
        reader.close();
    }
```

I can open the pdf, and it has the correct amount of pages, but the pages are all blank.

My initial thought is that it might got something to do with character codes to do, like some setting in my java project, intellij etc.

Alternatively, I don't actually need to put it in a file. I just need to download it so I can upload it to another place. However, the pdf should of course be working in either case. I'm really just putting it in an actual file to check if it works.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't use a reader, that's for characters. Use an input stream, that's for bytes.

Comment: **DON'T USE A `Reader` FOR BINARY STREAMS** (why would you think that casting random bytes from a gzip to a `char` would be a good idea?!)

Comment: Lexicons or Boris, please make that an answer.

Comment: @lexicore I have tried a bunch of different ways of outputting it into a file. My current implementation is the latest approach I tried, and it is the approach that have been the closest to working (it produced the least corrupt pdf files). I know an implementation that is close to work and a implementation that actually works are two completely different things, though :-)

Comment: @BoristheSpider As I say in my previous comment, the Reader is just one of many approaches I've tried. Also, there is no difference between casting it to a char or directly writing the integer. I just tried to cast is because I saw someone do it in some code snippet somewhere - I was simply just testing.

Comment: I will try the binary stream implementation again and come back with a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my new implementation, which solves my question:

```
public void readPDFfromURL(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    URL myURL = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
    urlCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    urlCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlCon.setDoInput(true);
    urlCon.connect();
    GZIPInputStream reader = new GZIPInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("document.pdf");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while((len = reader.read(buffer)) != -1){
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    fos.close();
    reader.close();
}
```